# Browser Displaying Plain Text

Tags: css, browser

When I view the site www.redfuryrevenge.com with a browser, I see only plain text, as if there is no CSS.  When I view it locally using Macrabbit Espresso preview, it looks fine.  I tried finding the error using Firefox console, debugger, etc., but nothing pops up for me.

I've never seen anything like this (except for a missing CSS file reference).

Please advise.

Comment: Your stylesheet URLs have 404 errors. You are linking with wrong path.

Comment: I've run it through a crawler and got 34 404 errors and 70 403 errors

Comment: How does your folder path to the stylesheet files look like?

Comment: That's what I don't get.  All of the css references are css/<filename>.css  . That should be right.

Comment: Give us a screenshot of your file directory

Comment: Here: http://www.redfuryrevenge.com/subdirectory.png .  That's /public_html/.  You can see index.html at the bottom of the screen shot and all of the relevant directories above: css, js, etc.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that for some reason you need to put the full root.
You can fix it adding the ./

Use the following syntax:
href="./css/style.css"

I've tried it and it should fix your issue